# Akra-Bazzi method for $n^2/\log_2(n)$ driving function

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computer-science, computational-mathematics

I came across $T(n) = 3T(n/3)+8T(n/4)+n^2/\log_2(n)$ with driving function $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\log_2(x)}$ in the CLRS 4th ed. textbook and am having a tough time applying the Akra-Bazzi method to it. My initial work involved finding a value $p$ for which $3(1/3)^p+8(1/4)^p = 1$ for which $p$ is approximately $1.85674$. Now using their expression to find the asymptotically tight bound $$T(n)=\Theta\!\left(n^p\left(1+\int_1^n \frac{f(x)}{x^{p+1}}dx\right)\right)= \Theta\!\left(n^p\left(1+\int_1^n \frac{x^{1-p}}{\log_2x}dx\right)\right)$$
For which I get an integral ($\int_1^n1/(x^{0.85674}\ln(x))dx$) that does not converge. Is there something incorrect to my work so far or does it simply mean this recurrence is unbounded?

Comment: Note that $
\int_1^n {\frac{{x^{1 - p} }}{{\log _2 x}}dx}  = \Theta \!\left( {\frac{{n^{2 - p} }}{{\log _2 n}}} \right)$, which you can check by L'Hôpital's rule. Thus $T(n)=\Theta \!\left( {\frac{{n^{2} }}{{\log _2 n}}} \right)$.

Comment: @Gary For $x\approx1$, $\log_2x\sim\frac{x-1}{\ln2}$ so the integrand $\sim\frac{\ln2}{x-1}$. Therefore, the integral diverges due to its lower bound being $1$. The _real_ resolution to the OP's problem is that Wikipedia is wrong to claim the lower bound should always be $1$. The lower bound should be one for which the integral converges. If the integral's $n\to\infty$ limit is $\infty$, the choice of lower bound is otherwise irrelevant.

Comment: @J.G. Indeed, thanks for the correction.